# QStyledItemDelegate partially select text of default QLineEdit editor

Tags: c++, qt, qstyleditemdelegate

I have a subclass of `QStyledItemDelegate` which at the moment does not reimplement any functions (for simplicity of the question).

With default `QStyledItemDelegate` implementation, when the user begins to edit text in a `QTableView`, the delegate draws a `QLineEdit` with the text from the model, and selects all of it (highlights all for editing).

The text represents file names such as "document.pdf". The user is allowed to edit this entire text, however, I only want to initially highlight the base name portion ("document") and not the suffix ("pdf"). How can I do this? (I don't need the logic of how to do this, I need to know how to get the `QStyledItemDelegate` to highlight a portion of text)

I've tried:

- in `setEditorData()` used `QLineEdit::setSelection()` to highlight some text. This has no effect.
- in `paint()` attempted to paint based on what other respondents have recommended to similar questions, but not success. I have little experience with `QPainter`. Here is an example: [Adjusting the selection behaviour of QStandardItem with QStyledItemDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491925/adjusting-the-selection-behaviour-of-qstandarditem-with-qstyleditemdelegate)

Please help, and thanks in advance. A code snippet with say selecting the first 3 characters of text would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can have your model return the filename without extension when the role is `Qt::EditRole`. But that way, the user won't be able to change the extension.

Comment: If you want the extension to be editable, You don't need to paint the selection, you need to really set the selection on the line edit to exclude the extension. The second approach you are mentioning won't work for you.

Comment: overriding `setEditorData` and set the selection you want there should've worked fine. But in [Qt source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp.html#4217), you can see a call to `le->selectAll();` after `setEditorData`. Unfortunately, that means that whatever selection you put in your `setEditorData` changes on that call. That's why your first approach doesn't work.

Comment: @Mike Any recommendations on how to select a part of the text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in my comments to the question, the problem with subclassing `QStyledItemDelegate` and trying to set any default selection in `setEditorData` like this:

```
void setEditorData(QWidget* editor, const QModelIndex &index)const{
    QStyledItemDelegate::setEditorData(editor, index);
    if(index.column() == 0){ //the column with file names in it
        //try to cast the default editor to QLineEdit
        QLineEdit* le= qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
        if(le){
            //set default selection in the line edit
            int lastDotIndex= le->text().lastIndexOf("."); 
            le->setSelection(0,lastDotIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

is that (in Qt code) after the view calls our `setEditorData` [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp#n4204), it tries to call `selectAll()` [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp#n4215) when the editor widget is a `QLineEdit`. That means that whatever selection we provide in `setEditorData` will be changed afterwards.

The only solution I could come up with, was to provide our selection in a queued manner. So that, our selection is set when execution is back into the event loop. Here is working example:

[image: screenshot]

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>

class FileNameDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate{
public:
    explicit FileNameDelegate(QObject* parent= nullptr)
        :QStyledItemDelegate(parent){}
    ~FileNameDelegate(){}

    void setEditorData(QWidget* editor, const QModelIndex &index)const{
        QStyledItemDelegate::setEditorData(editor, index);
        //the column with file names in it
        if(index.column() == 0){
            //try to cast the default editor to QLineEdit
            QLineEdit* le= qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
            if(le){
                QObject src;
                //the lambda function is executed using a queued connection
                connect(&src, &QObject::destroyed, le, [le](){
                    //set default selection in the line edit
                    int lastDotIndex= le->text().lastIndexOf(".");
                    le->setSelection(0,lastDotIndex);
                }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
            }
        }
    }
};

//Demo program

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QStandardItemModel model;
    QList<QStandardItem*> row;
    QStandardItem item("document.pdf");
    row.append(&item);
    model.appendRow(row);
    FileNameDelegate delegate;
    QTableView tableView;
    tableView.setModel(&model);
    tableView.setItemDelegate(&delegate);
    tableView.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

This may sound like a hack, but I decided to write this until someone has a better approach to the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much Mike. This works perfectly with a very minor modification to your code to remove the line if(index.column() == 0) since I am editing a column > 0. It does look like a work around, do you think it's worth to submit a bug report to Qt to provide better API for accessing the widget so that the user has full control over it? Thank you very much :)

Comment: @CSLover , you are welcome. That's what I meant by putting it, you need to change it to the column were you have file names :)

Comment: @CSLover , I am not really sure about the bug report. But personally, I don't think this is really worth submitting a bug report. They seem to put the call to `le->selectAll()` for `QLineEdit`s, so that users who override `setEditorData` are not obliged to to call `selectAll()` to make the text in their line edit selected by default. Omitting that call may cause a lot of already written code display a `QLineEdit` with no selection by default.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks again, much appreciated.

Comment: Could this be done by overriding a method of QLineEdit instead? I'm looking to have the text not selected by default but am struggling to make a python equivalent of your connect call.

Comment: @BrookeWallace, I don't think that you can achieve a similar effect by customizing your `QLineEdit` solely. In my opinion, `QLineEdit` is just a widget, that selects all its text when someone else tells it to do so (i.e. the widget itself is not responsible to decide what to select). In our case, `QAbstractItemView::edit` is the responsible one, because it calls `selectAll()` (somewhere during its call to `QAbstractItemViewPrivate::openEditor`).

Comment: @BrookeWallace, You might be able to get somewhere by overriding [`QAbstractItemView::edit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#edit-1), and provide your selection at the end. However, Qt does not seem to provide a public API to get the created editor for some index (e.g. see the internal function [`QAbstractItemViewPrivate::editorForIndex`](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp?h=5.15.0#n4353)). I don't know if there is a workaround that does not involve relying on Qt internals if you choose to go this route...