# How can exclude the file extension when i rename the item in QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

Now the action to rename will choose all the text i wanted to change ,but i want to keep the file extension used to be.
I don't want the user change the extension when they don't want to that.
How can i solve the problem.
thanks.

Comment: Configure or override the `QTextLineEdit` respectively which is used.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat did you mean that i should used QLineedit?

Comment: @Scheff'sCat by delegate, i replace the editer with qlineedit,but it still cant change the selection,even used setSelection().

Comment: Yeah, that was what I meant, and, yeah, `QLineEdit`, of course... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved,
first,inherited by qstyledelegate and replace the editor by qlineedit
second,see
[QStyledItemDelegate partially select text of default QLineEdit editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39667510/qstyleditemdelegate-partially-select-text-of-default-qlineedit-editor)